# Font color of mode line becomes black in emacsclient

Tags: emacs

I notice this problem recently, whenever I use `emacsclient` to start a new client, font color of the mode line becomes black.

I can produce this problem with following step :

```
emacs -q --daemon  # start the server
emacsclient # bring up the client
```

use customze-theme to load "wombat" theme

[image: mode line color works perfectly]

`C-x c` leave client, then bring up client again

[image: bad mode-line]

Dose anyone know what's the problem ?

Emacs version :

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.4) of 2013-10-03 on louvi, modified by Debian

Comment: Use `M-x customize-face` with `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive` to see whether they are what you want. If not, change them.

Comment: There seems to be a bug when using `load-theme` that makes mode-line set to #2c2c2c on new frames regardless of the value for mode-line in the theme or any other setting. I devised a hack based on [this emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SettingFrameColorsForEmacsClient) in order to work around it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my workaround based on @DanAloni's comment:

```lisp
(defun rangi/reload-theme ()
  (when window-system
      (load-theme 'afternoon)))

(defadvice server-create-window-system-frame
  (after reload-theme-on-frame-created ())
  "Reload theme when a frame is created"
  (rangi/reload-theme))

(ad-activate 'server-create-window-system-frame)
(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'rangi/reload-theme t)
```

I simply load theme again when frame is created, although it required you to hard code theme name.

Not sure whether this bug will be fixed in 24.4 or not